# ArgParse argument error if default or given value None

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

When parsing the arguments for my program, I'd like to be able to also take certain arguments from the environment if not specified as arguments to the program.

I currently have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Foo Bar Baz")
parser.add_argument('--metadata-api-user', type=str,
                    help='Username for basic authentication access to the metadata API. If not given, will be extracted from env variable {}'.format("API_USER"),
                    default=os.environ.get("API_USER"))
parser.add_argument('--metadata-api-password', type=str,
                    help='Password for basic authentication access to the metadata API. If not given, will be extracted from env variable {}'.format("API_PASS"),
                    default=os.environ.get("API_PASS"))
parser.add_argument('--version', type=int, help='Version number', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--location', type=str, help='Location to place thing (default: ./)',default="./")

args = parser.parse_args(args)
```

This provides the functionality that I want, but if the env variables are not given *and* they are not given in the command line, I'd like argparse to raise an ArgumentError.

environ[keyname] would raise a keyerror when creating arguments if it was only specified on the command line and not in the env variables, which isn't great.

Something like 'allow-none'=false would be great as a parameter when creating the argument, but if anyone knows another solution to this that would be awesome.

Comment: I think custom actions might help you. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: @serbia99 I had a go at implementing a custom action for it, but unfortunately the action isn't called if the default is used, and the only way the default isn't used is if a value is specified which means users would have to give a value anyway or get an error. cheers anyway!

Comment: Post parsing is the way to go,  As you note the `action.__call__` is only run when the user provides the argument.  And there's nothing in the default handling that would trigger an ArgumentError, especially not one that takes a custom message.

Comment: subclassing is the way to go, in the subclass just make the argument required when `default` is `None`.

Answer (score 4):

`default` will simply return the given value if the user doesn't provide one, however it has a special case for `None` and for strings.

Passing `None` to `default` will short circuit and return `None`.

Passing a string to `default` will return a parsed string using the `type` constructor.

I implemented a custom parameterized type called `not_none`, which will attempt to parse the string with a given type constructor, or fail loudly if the string is empty.

```py
import argparse
from os import environ
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

def not_none(type_constructor: Callable[[str], T] = str):
    """Convert a string to a type T."""
    def parse(s: str) -> T:
        """argparse will call this function if `s` is an empty string, but not when `s` is None."""
        if not s:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return type_constructor(s)
    return parse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo', help="A foo...", type=not_none(int), default='1')
    parser.add_argument('--bar', help="A bar...", type=not_none(), default=environ.get('BAR', ''))
    # args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', '1'])
    args = parser.parse_args(['--bar', 'BAR'])
    print(args.foo, args.bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is to subclass the argument parser to transparently implement the logic you described:

```py
class SaneArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    """
    Argument parser for which arguments are required on the CLI unless:
      - required=False is provided
        and/or
      - a default value is provided that is not None.
    """
    def add_argument(self, *args, default=None, **kwargs):
        if default is None:
            # Tentatively make this argument required
            kwargs.setdefault("required", True)
        super().add_argument(*args, **kwargs, default=default)
```

You'd use it as usual:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = SaneArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--foo", default=os.environ.get("FOO"))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

Of course, providing an argument on the CLI works as usual:

```
$ ./prog.py --foo=42
Namespace(foo='42')
```

Providing an argument in the environment also works:

```
$ FOO=42 ./prog.py
Namespace(foo='42')
```

And providing no argument at all raises an `ArgumentError`:

```
$ ./prog.py 
usage: prog.py [-h] --foo FOO
prog.py: error: the following arguments are required: --foo
```

---

Note that catching `ArgumentError` is only possible since Python 3.9 when using `exit_on_error=False`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution, so I've had to go with adding  following for every argument that can be obtained from env variables:

```
api_user_action = parser.add_argument('--metadata-api-user', type=str,
                    help='Username for basic authentication access to the metadata API. If not given, will be extracted from env variable {}'.format("API_USER"),
                    default=os.environ.get("API_USER"))

...

if args.metadata_api_user is None:
    raise argparse.ArgumentError(api_user_action,
                                 "API Username was not supplied in either command line or environment variables. \n" + parser.format_help())
```

This prints the usage and an appropriate error message if they aren't supplied by either, but it needs to be repeated from every argument that this can apply to.

Comment: You could collect those `actions` in a list, and iterate over that list after parsing.  Then the test can be written as: `if getattr(args,`action.dest`) is None: ...`

Comment: You could even leave the `environ.get` to this stage - unless you want to show it in the `help` line.

Comment: @hpaulj that sounds like a nicer way of doing it for sure, thanks :)

Comment: add required = os.environ.get("API_USER", None) is None

Answer (score 0):

why not check for the environment variable while building the arguments?

```
if "API_USER" in os.environ:
    parser.add_argument('--metadata-api-user', type=str, default=os.environ.get("API_USER"))
else:
    parser.add_argument('--metadata-api-user', type=str)
```

this seems like the easiest way to get the result you need.

Comment: This is not answering the OP's problem: when the env var is not set (hence `default=None`), he wants `parse_args()` to raise an `ArgumentError` exception (or rather exit which is actually the default behaviour). But in your case the argument is simply set to `None`. You'd actually need to add `required=True` in the "env var not set" case to do what is asked.